# Production configration on a public GitHub repository

Tags: github, configuration

I have a project that will be published on GitHub, but we don't want to expose our production configuration to the public, e.g. items like: api url, api key, and 3rd party keys.
Many projects do it but using `.ignore` is not the desired way to achieve this.
What is the way to do this so that the repository has all the configuration on company machines but not included on GitHub?

Example projects:

[Wire ios APP](https://github.com/wireapp/wire-ios#how-to-build-the-open-source-client)

[Artsy](https://github.com/artsy/eidolon)

[kickstarter](https://github.com/kickstarter/ios-oss)

Comment: Why is "using .ignore is not the desired way to achieve this"? Production credentials definitely shouldn't be checked into version control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push code to Github hiding the API keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342276/how-to-push-code-to-github-hiding-the-api-keys)